# Apply mathematical function(s) to an array?

Tags: python, function

[math that needs to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YllkM.jpg)

I have a data file that will contain an XYZ coordinates for several atoms.

I need to have the molecule oriented such that the two sulfur atoms are resting on the x axis.

I know the math behind what I need to do, I am just unsure how to apply this to an array in python.

What I am looking to do is the rotation of a vector in 3 dimensions. I have all the xyz coordinates and i am going to first manually adjust the coordinates so that one of my sulfurs is resting at the origin (0,0,0). From there I need to apply trig functions to rotate the atoms so that the molecule as a whole will be "laying flat." What I mean by this is so that both of my sulfurs in the molecule are resting on the x-axis.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried so far. Even if it's dead wrong. If you know the math behind what you're trying to do, your already half the way there. It shouldn't be to translate it to Python code.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an array x and want array of the results of applying function f to each of them, this will do it:

```
[f(e) for e in x]
```

Comment: Not trying to be snarky just curios. How did you know this is what the OP wanted? In other words, how did you understand he wanted a list comprehension from _"I need to have the molecule oriented such that the two sulfur atoms are resting on the x axis."_? Is there some math that I don't understand? (BTW, I didn't down-vote).

Comment: "I am unsure how to apply this to an array in python"

Comment: Ah, I see. I took that as meaning _"I am unsure of how to apply this math to an array in Python"_.

Comment: If one was looking for help w/ the applying some math, wouldn't you need to, I don't know, say what that math is?  Or ask how to write the needed function?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that I didn't add the important part, the picture of the math that needs done.

Comment: I can code all of the math, I'm just unsure how to handle arrays.